# Parsing a SCPI-like file in C

Tags: c

I am writing (in C) a parser of a file with SCPI-like commands. The file is divided in several sections. Example:

```
#section1
*IDN?
*STB?
#section2
*RST
```

The problem is that I have to be able to navigate between the sections with the following commands:

```
#if:...goto:section1
```

These commands are also the part of the file.

My question is: what is the most efficient way to implement it (ofc, I do not need a code, only the idea)?

I was thinking to make an array with the commands to navigate around, with sections corresponding to the different offsets. But I am not sure if would be efficient-enough in C (usually I don't write in C, I use the other languages).

So, is this a good way to write it in C (to make array of strings with the commands), or I should implement it in some other way? Thanks.

Comment: "Navigate" is not a part of "parse". Divide the problem properly.

Comment: If you want to parse it, you can use [Flex & bison](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html). There are a ton of tutorials and book out there. I'd advice to first parse the file, store the parsing in a syntax tree and then you can do whatever you want/need.

Comment: Well, the question is actually about how to parse the file in order to implement the navigation. Not about how to implement the navigation.

Comment: there is an open source SCPI parser on git http://j123b567.github.io/scpi-parser/basic/code/ maybe see the source code